# Why AVAudioPlayer always shows -160 dB averagePower level

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I have `AVAudioPlayer` initialized in my macOS app like below:

```
do {
    let audioFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp3")!
    let audioURL = URL(filePath: audioFile)
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
} catch {
    fatalError()
}
```

When I click the "Start" button it starts to play sound correctly but the printed `dBLevel` is always -160.

```
Button("Start") {
    player!.play()
    var dbLevel = Float(0)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        player!.updateMeters()
        dbLevel = 0
        for n in 0..<player!.numberOfChannels {
            dbLevel += player!.averagePower(forChannel: n)
        }
        dbLevel = dbLevel / Float(player!.numberOfChannels)
        print(dbLevel)
    })
}
```

Note that Xcode writes the following message to the console

> AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002d8d0e0>...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AddInstanceForFactory%3A+No+factory+ for lots of info about the console message (which appears to be completely separate from your actual issue and solution for the meter).

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution quickly - this line was needed:

```
 player!.isMeteringEnabled = true
```